# Remove the author from the footer of all slides except in the titlepage

Tags: beamer, header-footer, titles

I want to remove the `\author` from all the slides except the start slide. I  have used Warsaw theme. I don't know how to go about this. Please help me

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\title[\insertframenumber/
\inserttotalframenumber]{Database}
\author{Mark dain \\ \scriptsize{(Reg.No 12345)} }
\institute{Dept. of Information \& Communication Technology}
\date{October 21,2012}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction
\item Algorithm for reducing finite automata
\item Reliability models
\item Reduction steps
\item References
\item Conclusion
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I dont want author to be displayed in the footer of the second frame.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Could you provide more information about the Beamer `theme` you are using? This will help people in answering you.

Comment: sory i edited my question. i have used Warsaw theme

Comment: Seen, but there's still one problem remaining: in the `titlepage` of the Warsaw theme the author could also be displayed in the `footline`, besides in the center of the frame. So say _i want to remove the \author from all the slides except the start slide_ it's a bit ambiguous because one could interpret that you still want, for the `titlepage`, the author in the footline.

Comment: Please, next time try to compose a [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). It is always preferable to post complete minimal working example rather than code snippets because this helps people to answer you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usetheme{Warsaw}    

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\ifnum\thepage=1\insertauthor\fi
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}


\title[\insertframenumber/
\inserttotalframenumber]{Database}
\author{Mark dain \\ \scriptsize{(Reg.No 12345)} }
\institute{Dept. of Information \& Communication Technology}
\date{October 21,2012}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction
\item Algorithm for reducing finite automata
\item Reliability models
\item Reduction steps
\item References
\item Conclusion
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which leads to:

[image]

Basically the lines of code that do the work are:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
    {%
      \leavevmode%
      \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\ifnum\thepage=1\insertauthor\fi
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
      \end{beamercolorbox}}%
      \vskip0pt%
    }
```

that replicate basically the standard `footline` defined by the `split` theme, but now the `author` is displayed only if the frame number is the titlepage (done via the `\ifnum` checking the value of the current page).

This works of course in case you just want to *remove* the author and not to display something else.

Comment: Glad of having helped you. `:)`